# Android animation crashing

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to do an animation where I move an imageview from bottom to top. I have this code so far

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    ImageView bubbles = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubbles);
    //bubbles.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    Animation animContentUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up_service);

    animContentUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    bubbles.startAnimation(animContentUp);  // line 48
}
```

slide_up_service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="700" 
      android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
      android:toXDelta="0%p"
      android:fromYDelta="0%"
      android:toYDelta="120%">
</translate>
```

But when I call `bubbles.startAnimation(animContentUp);` it crashes.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Also, the xml came from a post asking how to move from top to bottom, how can I make it bottom to top?

Thanks

```
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.arin/android.arin.LoginScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.arin.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:48)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
05-31 16:49:31.035: E/AndroidRuntime(3026):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: and what is in LoginScreen.java:48?? also post the oncreate of the LoginScreen

Comment: I added it, line 48 is ` bubbles.startAnimation(animContentUp);`

Comment: can you also post the xml activity_login_screen

Comment: it seems bubbles imageview variable is becoming null...

Comment: yes that was my observation..

Comment: Apparently `findViewById(R.id.bubbles)` returns null. Are you sure your `R.layout.activity_login_screen` layout contains an `ImageView` with id `bubbles`?

Comment: Also the xml code of the bubbles imageview is on the fragment_loginscreen.xml not the activity_loginscreen.xml, how can I do the findviewbyid relative to the fragment xml? When creating a new activity, it creates both these xml files so I added the code to the fragment one...

Comment: I made a new post to detail the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974538/how-to-get-a-view-from-a-fragment-layout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The `NullPointerException` probably refers to bubbles, so `findViewById()` doesn't find Your ImageView. Did you get your ID right?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a view that is not in your current layout.. `findViewById(R.id.bubbles)` this will return null because it is located in your `fragment_loginscreen` not in the `activity_loginscreen` which you used as a layout in your activity

**solution:**

put your image view into your `activity_loginscreen` layout or simply change the layout of the activity to `fragment_loginscreen`

Answer (score 0):

`bubbles` was null because there is no `View` with id `@id/bubbles` in `activity_login_screen`  layout.