# How to get a view from a fragment layout in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an xml like this

activity_loginscreen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="android.arin.LoginScreen"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and then gragment_loginscreen.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/LoginView"
    tools:context="android.arin.LoginScreen$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bubbles"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bubbles_cd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:alpha=".75"
        android:src="@drawable/bubbles" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my java file I have

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    ImageView bubbles = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubbles);
}
```

But bubbles ends up being null because it can't find it because its looking in the activity xml one, but really the imageview is in the fragment one, how can I get it to look there?

Thanks

Comment: create aconstructor in the PlaceHolderFragment and pass the cobtext of your activity.. sorry cant reply in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Make your `PlaceholderFragment` fragment `onCreateView(....)` like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gragment_loginscreen, container, false);
    ImageView bubbles = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bubbles);
    return view;
}
```

and used `getActivity()` as a `Context` in `Fragment` like

```
Animation animContentUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up_service);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the imageView in your `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView` and in the `PlaceholderFragment` inflate the layout `gragment_loginscreen` which will generate a view..

**example:**

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gragment_loginscreen, container, false);
        ImageView bubbles = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.bubbles);
        return view;
}
```

Comment: @omega you did begin transacting a fragment so you should do it inside the fragment class(PlaceholderFragment) not in the activity class

Comment: If I get bubbles from there, then how do I get the right context to use for this `Animation animContentUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up_service);`